# Tortoise and Hare Algorithm - Linked List Cycles

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

In the well known Tortoise/Hare algorithm, why does the hare need to move at twice the speed of the tortoise? when I tried to implement it at first, I tried to simply move the hare one ahead of the tortoise, not at twice the speed, and that  didn't work.

Comment: The hare has to "catch up" to the tortoise for this to work. It can't if they're both moving at the same speed.

Comment: I see. So if you set the hare to initially be the next value by default, and then incremented them at the same rate, the two of them would just keep going up and never meet!

Comment: Also, the hare doesn't have to move at twice the speed as the tortoise, just faster. Twice the speed is just easy to describe an implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

per Mark Ransom: The hare has to "catch up" to the tortoise for this to work. It can't if they're both moving at the same speed.